# Computing AABBs of many objects on image

Tags: c++, image-processing

I'm writing handwrite recognize system using ANN, but I've got a problem:
I want to seperate characters on scanned image and get AABB of each (I don't want to draw it on image but only compute this)

It can be assumed that characters are only black and background are only white (I have written thresholding algorithm already)

```
std::vector < unsigned char > px; // pixel data (RGBARGBARGBARGBA...)
unsigned w, h; // width and height of image

lodepng::decode( px, w, h, infile ); // i use LodePNG to decode image

for( int i = 0; i < px.size(); i += 4 )
{
    unsigned char & r = px[ i ], & g = px[ i + 1 ], & b = px[ i + 2 ], & a = px[ i + 3 ];

    // and what now?
}

lodepng::encode( outfile, px, w, h );
```

[Image of problem](http://www.mediafire.com/view/v9jqilnkgtrgwo5/seg2.PNG) (sorry but I haven't got enough rep to post images :( )

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box)

Comment: Axis Aligned Bounding Box - ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image processing task shown in your image is known as "segmentation". There are plenty of methods to do so. The easiest is to pick the first black pixel (top-left most) and check if any of the  <strike>4 pixels to its right (x+=1) or directly below it (y+=1, x+={-1,0,1}) are also black.</strike>  8 neighboring pixels are also black. Add these to the set of pixels belonging to the same letter and recurse. To prevent infinite recursion, you should only check neighbours of points that you added in the previous recursion, and not add points twice. You can keep track of points that you've added by creating a blank canvas the size of your input and setting the pixel value to the iteration in which you found it. So the first pixel gets value 1, its neighbours get value 2, the neighbours of the neighbours get value 3, etc.

At a certain point you've found the bottom-left pixel of the letter, so you'd erase them all in your input. This ensures that the new top-left black pixel belongs to the second letter.

The Axis Aligned Bounding Box is now just the min/max x/y over all pixels of a letter.

Comment: True. But since one of the 4 neighbour pixels you check on each iteration is at y+=1, x+=-1 you'll walk the diagonal to the bottom left.

Answer (score 0):

I used diffrent algorithm (thanks for MSalters for giving this idea). Maybe it can help someone, so i give pseudocode for this. (i tested it)

```
Copy image to image2
for each(Pixel p in image2)
{
  if(p is black)
  {
    Add p to container
    Set p color to white
    Call findNeighbours(p position)

    left top of aabb = (lowest x of pixels in container, lowest y of pixels in container)
    right down of aabb = (highest x of pixels in container, highest y of pixels in container)
    Save this aabb
    Clear container
  }
}
All objects found, all pixels should be white

function findNeighbours(x, y)
{
  for each(neighbour of pixel (x, y))
  {
    if(this neighbour is black)
    {
      Set this neighbour's color to white
      Add this neighbour's position to container
      Call findNeighbours(this neighbour's position)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But this algorithm is not for character recognision: it cannot recognise e.g. 'i' character :(. I need to work on this yet

Comment: Is the problem that the dot is disconnected? That's a fair question on its own.

Comment: I will train ANN to recognise 'i' without dot and then recognise dot and then connect it into one character

Comment: That's not reliable. Handwriting is too smudged for that. You'll keep confusing the l and i. You'll have to turn l's into i's if you spot a dot (or if the context suggests it's appropriate - `thls` is a clear hint that you missed a dot)